# How to create a list of heterogeneous datatypes without using sum-types or copies

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

**The use-case:** An app to follow users across several messaging services. There's a `TwitterAccount` datatype, a `FacebookAccount` datatype, etc. These could easily be joined together with an `Account` sum-type, but the next level of the hierarchy leads to my problem.

A `TwitterAccount` has a list of `TwitterPost`s, a `FacebookAccount` has a list of `FacebookPost`s, etc.

**My task:** I want to be able to put all posts for the last 10 days from all accounts into a single list, and extract the common time and message body fields from them for display.

**My failed approach:** I thought that if every class of `Post` implemented a typeclass like `SimplePost` exposing functions `messageBody` and `messageTime` that that might solve my problem, but I can't create a list of `[SimpleMessage]`.

I want to maintain the invariant that a `TwitterAccount` *can only contain*`TwitterPost`s, and so on, so I can't use sum-types. I'd prefer not to create copies of objects to do this.

*What is the best, cleanest, most Haskell-ish design for this problem?*

**UPDATE**
This isn't an answer, but as an alternative to the four solutions provided by recursion.ninja and Helder Pereira I've been thinking if I can meet my invariants using phantom types, and `Account` and `Post` types that hold all possible information required by all providers. However the use of tuples, and the awkward logic, means it doesn't scale very well; perhaps this should be in a different question.

```js
{-# LANGUAGE EmptyDataDecls #-}   

-- Some FSharpisms
(|>) = flip ($)
(<|) = ($)
infixr 0 <|


data Twitter
data Facebook
data LinkedIn

data Post a = Post{
    postBody :: String,
    postDate :: UTCTime,
    postForwarded :: Bool,
    postFriendMentions :: [UserName]
    } deriving (Show, Eq)

data Account a = Account {
    accountName  :: String,
    accountPosts :: [Post a]
    } deriving (Show, Eq)

data User = User {
    userName   :: String,
    userTweets :: Account Twitter,
    userFaces  :: Account Facebook,
    userLinks  :: Account LinkedIn
    }

prettyShowUtc :: UTCTime -> String
prettyShowUtc utc = ...

prettyShow :: Post a -> String
prettyShow p = prettyShowUtc (postDate p) ++ " : " ++ show (postBody p)

showOrderedOf2 :: ([Post a], [Post b]) -> [String]
showOrderedOf2 ([], []) = []
showOrderedOf2 (ls, []) = map prettyShow ls
showOrderedOf2 ([], rs) = map prettyShow rs
showOrderedOf2 ((l:ls), (r:rs)) = 
    if postDate l < postDate r
    then prettyShow l : showOrderedOf2 (ls, (r:rs))
    else prettyShow r : showOrderedOf2 ((l:ls), rs)

showOrderedOf3 :: ([Post a], [Post b], [Post c]) -> [String]
showOrderedOf3 ([], [], []) = []
showOrderedOf3 (as, [], []) = map postBody as
showOrderedOf3 ([], bs, []) = map postBody bs
showOrderedOf3 ([], [], cs) = map postBody cs
showOrderedOf3 (as, bs, []) = showOrderedOf2 (as, bs)
showOrderedOf3 ([], bs, cs) = showOrderedOf2 (bs, cs)
showOrderedOf3 (as, [], cs) = showOrderedOf2 (as, cs)
showOrderedOf3 ((a:as), (b:bs), (c:cs)) =
    let (adate, bdate, cdate) = (postDate a, postDate b, postDate c)
        minDate = minimum [adate, bdate, cdate]
    in
    if adate == minDate
    then prettyShow a : showOrderedOf3 (as, (b:bs), (c:cs))
    else (if bdate == minDate
         then prettyShow b : showOrderedOf3 ((a:as), bs, (c:cs))
         else prettyShow c : showOrderedOf3 ((a:as), (b:bs), cs))

createAndShowSample :: IO ()
createAndShowSample =
    let faceAc = Account {...} :: Account Facebook
        twitAc = Account {...} :: Account Twitter
        linkAc = Account {...} :: Account LinkedIn
    in 
    showOrderedOf3 (accountPosts faceAc, accountPosts twitAc, accountPosts linkAc)
        |> intercalate "\n"
        |> putStrLn
```

Comment: Make them both instances of some typeclass, then enable the `ExistencialTypes` laguange extension.

Comment: Is that best Haskell practice, since, it's only available via a GHC extension? Is there any "pure" Haskell way of doing this?

Comment: It's a GHC extension, see my answer for the *right way*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should abstract the `FaceBookAccount` and the `TwitterAccount` to instances of `SocialMediaAccount`

**Haskell Code:**

```
import Control.Applicative ((<$>))
import Data.List
import Data.Ord
import Data.Time

data FaceBookAccount = FaceBookAccount [FaceBookPost]
data TwitterAccount  = TwitterAccount  [TwitterPost]
data FaceBookPost    = FaceBookPost String UTCTime
data TwitterPost     = TwitterPost  String UTCTime

data SocialMediaAccount 
   = SocialMediaAccount 
   { accountPosts :: [SocialMediaPost]
   }
data SocialMediaPost 
   = SocialMediaPost
   { postBody :: String
   , postTime :: UTCTime
   }

class SocialMedia a where
  simpleAccount  :: a -> SocialMediaAccount  

instance SocialMedia FaceBookAccount where
  simpleAccount (FaceBookAccount xs) = SocialMediaAccount $ f <$> xs
    where 
      f (FaceBookPost text time) = SocialMediaPost text time

instance SocialMedia TwitterAccount where
  simpleAccount (TwitterAccount xs) = SocialMediaAccount $ f <$> xs
    where 
      f (TwitterPost text time) = SocialMediaPost text time

getAllMessages :: (SocialMedia a, SocialMedia b) => a -> b -> [SocialMediaPost]
getAllMessages xs ys = sortBy (comparing postTime) 
                     $ extract xs
                    ++ extract ys
  where
    extract :: SocialMedia a => a -> [SocialMediaPost]
    extract = accountPosts . simpleAccount
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. It's very clean, but it is however, equivalent to just creating copies of all messages. Is that unavoidable then? I was hoping there was some functional design-pattern that I was missing.

Comment: @Feenaboccles It's not exactly equivenlent. Since Haskell *purely-functional* language, it will reuse the `String`s, `UTCTime`s, and `List`s in memory when creating the "new" `SocialMediaAccount` types. Essentially you will be creating new references, but not copying the entire "objects." This is one of the benefits of *type purity.*

Comment: Your point is true of imperative languages too: passing values by reference is what happens (unsafely) in idiomatic Java. However in Java, given a `SimpleMessage` interface, you wouldn't have to create a new wrapper type around the same fields, for every value in the input lists. I'd seen that solution, and the very closely related `ExistentialQuantification` extension before: I was hoping I could avoid them.

Comment: @Feenaboccles as far as I know, they are your only options. That is just how the type-system works... It may be optemized away by the compiler. Given the purity guarantees, the compiler can safely make agressive optemizations.

Comment: I prefer this solution to the one based on existential types and typeclasses. Maybe I'd also skip over the `SocialMediaAccount` type and use `[SocialMediaPost]` directly, but that's a minor point.

Answer (score 3):

I implemented three possible solutions that may help you decide what better fits your requirements.

**Solution 1: [Existential Types](https://wiki.haskell.org/Existential_type)**

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

import Data.Time

data FacebookAccount = FacebookAccount [FacebookPost]
data TwitterAccount  = TwitterAccount  [TwitterPost]

data FacebookPost = FacebookPost String UTCTime
  deriving Show
data TwitterPost  = TwitterPost  String UTCTime
  deriving Show

-- Account

class Account a where
  posts :: a -> [AnyPost]

data AnyAccount = forall a . Account a => AnyAccount a

instance Account AnyAccount where
  posts (AnyAccount a) = posts a

instance Account FacebookAccount where
  posts (FacebookAccount ps) = map AnyPost ps

instance Account TwitterAccount where
  posts (TwitterAccount ps) = map AnyPost ps

-- Post

class Show p => Post p where
  text :: p -> String
  date :: p -> UTCTime

data AnyPost = forall a . Post a => AnyPost a

instance Show AnyPost where
  show (AnyPost p) = show p

instance Post AnyPost where
  text (AnyPost p) = text p
  date (AnyPost p) = date p

instance Post FacebookPost where
  text (FacebookPost t _) = t
  date (FacebookPost _ d) = d

instance Post TwitterPost where
  text (TwitterPost t _) = t
  date (TwitterPost _ d) = d


allPostsSince :: UTCTime -> [AnyAccount] -> [AnyPost]
allPostsSince d as = filter (\p -> date p >= d) $ concatMap posts as

facebook = FacebookAccount
  [ FacebookPost "Hello" $ UTCTime (fromGregorian 2015 8 14) (secondsToDiffTime 0)
  , FacebookPost "Olá"   $ UTCTime (fromGregorian 2015 8 12) (secondsToDiffTime 0)
  ]

twitter = TwitterAccount
  [ TwitterPost "Bonjour" $ UTCTime (fromGregorian 2015 8 13) (secondsToDiffTime 0)
  , TwitterPost "Hola"    $ UTCTime (fromGregorian 2015 8 10) (secondsToDiffTime 0)
  ]

main :: IO ()
main = do today <- getCurrentTime
          let fiveDays = 5 * 24 * 60 * 60
              fiveDaysAgo = (-fiveDays) `addUTCTime` today
              posts = allPostsSince fiveDaysAgo [AnyAccount facebook, AnyAccount twitter]
          mapM_ print posts
```

---

**Solution 2: [Universal Type](https://wiki.haskell.org/Heterogenous_collections#A_Universal_type)**

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}

import Control.Applicative
import Data.Dynamic
import Data.Maybe
import Data.Time

data FacebookAccount = FacebookAccount [FacebookPost]
  deriving Typeable
data TwitterAccount  = TwitterAccount  [TwitterPost]
  deriving Typeable

data FacebookPost = FacebookPost String UTCTime
  deriving (Show, Typeable)
data TwitterPost  = TwitterPost  String UTCTime
  deriving (Show, Typeable)

getPosts :: Dynamic -> [Dynamic]
getPosts dyn = fromJust $  (\ (FacebookAccount ps) -> map toDyn ps) <$> fromDynamic dyn
                       <|> (\ (TwitterAccount  ps) -> map toDyn ps) <$> fromDynamic dyn
                       <|> error "Type mismatch"

getDate :: Dynamic -> UTCTime
getDate dyn = fromJust $  (\ (FacebookPost _ d) -> d) <$> fromDynamic dyn
                      <|> (\ (TwitterPost  _ d) -> d) <$> fromDynamic dyn
                      <|> error "Type mismatch"

toString :: Dynamic -> String
toString dyn = fromJust $  (\ p@(FacebookPost _ _) -> show p) <$> fromDynamic dyn
                       <|> (\ p@(TwitterPost  _ _) -> show p) <$> fromDynamic dyn
                       <|> error "Type mismatch"

allPostsSince :: UTCTime -> [Dynamic] -> [Dynamic]
allPostsSince d as = filter (\p -> getDate p >= d) $ concatMap getPosts as

facebook = FacebookAccount
  [ FacebookPost "Hello" $ UTCTime (fromGregorian 2015 8 14) (secondsToDiffTime 0)
  , FacebookPost "Olá"   $ UTCTime (fromGregorian 2015 8 12) (secondsToDiffTime 0)
  ]

twitter = TwitterAccount
  [ TwitterPost "Bonjour" $ UTCTime (fromGregorian 2015 8 13) (secondsToDiffTime 0)
  , TwitterPost "Hola"    $ UTCTime (fromGregorian 2015 8 10) (secondsToDiffTime 0)
  ]

main :: IO ()
main = do today <- getCurrentTime
          let fiveDays = 5 * 24 * 60 * 60
              fiveDaysAgo = (-fiveDays) `addUTCTime` today
              posts = allPostsSince fiveDaysAgo [toDyn facebook, toDyn twitter]
          mapM_ (putStrLn . toString) posts
```

---

**Solution 3: Back to Basics**

This is a minimalist solution, which does not even enforce that all the posts in one account have that account's type.

```
import Data.Time

data AccountType = Facebook
                 | Twitter
  deriving Show

data Account = Account AccountType [Post]

data Post = Post AccountType String UTCTime
  deriving Show

allPostsSince :: UTCTime -> [Account] -> [Post]
allPostsSince d as = filter (\ (Post _ _ pd) -> pd >= d) $ concatMap (\ (Account _ ps) -> ps) as

facebook = Account Facebook
  [ Post Facebook "Hello" $ UTCTime (fromGregorian 2015 8 14) (secondsToDiffTime 0)
  , Post Facebook "Olá"   $ UTCTime (fromGregorian 2015 8 12) (secondsToDiffTime 0)
  ]

twitter = Account Twitter
  [ Post Twitter "Bonjour" $ UTCTime (fromGregorian 2015 8 13) (secondsToDiffTime 0)
  , Post Twitter "Hola"    $ UTCTime (fromGregorian 2015 8 10) (secondsToDiffTime 0)
  ]

main :: IO ()
main = do today <- getCurrentTime
          let fiveDays = 5 * 24 * 60 * 60
              fiveDaysAgo = (-fiveDays) `addUTCTime` today
              posts = allPostsSince fiveDaysAgo [facebook, twitter]
          mapM_ print posts
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this, it's very interesting. All methods do seem to involve wrapping the disparate types inside of some unified marker type however, and seem like more complex versions of recursion.ninja's approach, which is why I'd prefer it if I had to choose.